# How do you use Espresso to test a SelectionTracker?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, selection, android-espresso

I would like to be able to use Espresso to select items in a `RecylcerView` that is used to set up a `SelectionTracker`. I would also like to be able to deselect items with Espresso.

This is the code for setting up the selection tracker for illustration purposes:

```
val selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(
    selectionID,
    recyclerView,
    stringAdapter.itemKeyProvider,
    createItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
    StorageStrategy.createStringStorage()
)
```

The debug version of my app has been manually tested, so I know that the `SelectionTracker` works correctly, however, I do not want to have to manually test it every time a change is made.

I have tried using Espresso to `longClick` an item:

```
    val toolbarId = withId(R.id.toolbar_activity_main)
    val toolbar = onView(toolbarId)
    toolbar.check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
    toolbar.check(
        matches(
            withInvisibleIcon(R.id.action_delete_toolbar_activity_main),
        )
    )
    val recyclerViewWithId = withId(R.id.fragment_editor_recycler_view)
    val recyclerView = onView(recyclerViewWithId)
    recyclerView.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    val itemView = onView(
        allOf(
            withParent(recyclerViewWithId),
            withChild(
                allOf(
                    withText("AA"),
                    withId(R.id.view_holder_item_text_view)
                )
            ),
            withId(R.id.view_holder_item),
            )
    )
    itemView.check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)))
    itemView.perform(longClick())
    toolbar.check(
        matches(
            withVisibleIcon(R.id.action_delete_toolbar_activity_main),
        )
    )
```

with the following `Matcher`s:

```
private fun withInvisibleIcon(@IdRes int: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with invisible icon id: $int")
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
            if (view !is MaterialToolbar) {
                return false
            }
            val item = view.menu.findItem(int)
            return (item.itemId == int) and (!item.isVisible)
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that the icon with `action_delete_toolbar_activity_main` does become visible if I set a breakpoint in the above code and manually long click an item while it is paused. I also become visible when manually testing the app.

```
private fun withVisibleIcon(@IdRes int: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with visible icon id: $int")
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
            if (view !is MaterialToolbar) {
                return false
            }
            val item = view.menu.findItem(int)
            return (item.itemId == int) and (item.isVisible)
        }
    }
}
```

This leads to an Exception:

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with visible icon id: 2131230778' doesn't match the selected view.
...
```

I have tried using `RecyclerViewAction`s to `longClick`:

```
    

recyclerView.perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<StringAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        0,
        longClick()
    ))
```

I have tried both methods with a custom click that is six and two thirds times longer than `longClick`

```
    enum class Tap : Tapper {
        LONGER_CLICK {
            override fun sendTap(
                uiController: UiController?,
                coordinates: FloatArray?,
                precision: FloatArray?,
                inputDevice: Int,
                buttonState: Int
            ): Tapper.Status {
                var downEvent = MotionEvents.sendDown(
                    uiController,
                    coordinates,
                    precision,
                    inputDevice,
                    buttonState
                ).down
                try {
                    // Duration before a press turns into a long press.
                    // Factor 1.5 is needed, otherwise a long press is not safely detected.
                    // See android.test.TouchUtils longClickView
                    val longPressTimeout =
                        (ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() * 10f).toLong()
                    uiController!!.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(longPressTimeout)
                    if (!MotionEvents.sendUp(uiController, downEvent)) {
                        MotionEvents.sendCancel(uiController, downEvent)
                        return Tapper.Status.FAILURE
                    }
                } finally {
                    downEvent!!.recycle()
                    downEvent = null
                }
                return Tapper.Status.SUCCESS
            }
    
            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun sendTap(
                uiController: UiController?,
                coordinates: FloatArray?,
                precision: FloatArray?
            ): Tapper.Status {
                return sendTap(
                    uiController,
                    coordinates,
                    precision,
                    InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN,
                    MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY
                )
            }
    
        }
    }
```

```
    recyclerView.perform(
    RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<StringAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        0,
        GeneralClickAction(
            Tap.LONGER_CLICK,
            GeneralLocation.VISIBLE_CENTER,
            Press.FINGER,
            InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN,
            MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY
        )
    )
)
```

I have debugged the `SelectionTracker` code, and it looks like it shouldn't matter what is clicked as long as the right coordinates are clicked, so I am at a loss.

I am starting to think it is a bug.

Update:
I have tried the following ugly workaround to click the item through the Activity containing the item, and the item still does not get selected.

```
val location = IntArray(2){0}
val cdl  = CountDownLatch(1)
scenario.onActivity {
    val recyclerView = it.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.fragment_editor_recycler_view)
    val ite = recyclerView.getChildAt(0)
    ite.getLocationOnScreen(location)
    cdl.countDown()
}
cdl.await()
val recyclerViewWithId = withId(R.id.fragment_editor_recycler_view)
onView(recyclerViewWithId).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
onView(withId(R.id.activity_main)).perform(
    GeneralClickAction(
        Tap.LONG,
        { FloatArray(location.size){ i -> (location[i]+1).toFloat() } },
        Press.FINGER,
        InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN,
        MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY
    )
)
```

Another update:

```
    val cdl  = CountDownLatch(1)
    scenario.onActivity {
        val recyclerView = it.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.fragment_editor_recycler_view)
        val ite = recyclerView.getChildAt(0)
        ite.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        cdl.countDown()
    }
    cdl.await()
    onView(isRoot()).perform(
        GeneralClickAction(
            Tap.LONG,
            { FloatArray(location.size){ i -> (location[i]+1).toFloat() } },
            Press.FINGER,
            InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN,
            MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY
        )
    )
```

Long click still does not trigger SelectionTracker when clicked through the root view. I have verified it is connected to the Fragment's RecyclerView. This is clearly a bug.

Comment: It'll grow on you :) It's kind of the normal form here. Anyway let's remove some unneeded comments.

Comment: There's some interesting usage of `onView` in your code, try to inline those variables that contain `onView(...)` only, and call it before each `.check` or chain `onView().check().check()`. But don't interleave xonView, yonView, xcheck, ycheck -> xonView, xcheck, yonView, ycheck. You might be missing crucial synchronization.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue